# Why is StartInfo (ProcessStartInfo) always empty?

Tags: .net, process

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.startinfo(VS.80).aspx):

> If you did not use the `Start` method to start a process, the `StartInfo` property does not reflect the parameters used to start the process. For example, if you use `GetProcesses` to get an array of processes running on the computer, the `StartInfo` property of each `Process` does not contain the original file name or arguments used to start the process.

Okay, that makes perfect sense.  My question is why are these parameters blank even when you do use `Process.Start()`?

For example:

```
Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("firefox.exe")
startInfo.Arguments = "www.stackoverflow.com"
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized
Process.Start(startInfo)
For Each proc As Process In Process.GetProcessesByName("firefox")
    Debug.Print(String.Format("ProcessID={0}; Arguments={1}", _
    proc.Id, proc.StartInfo.Arguments))
Next proc
```

In this case even though I provided Arguments, that property is still empty.

What gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are still doing a GetProcess, thus it continues to work the same. The fact that you started it doesn't make a difference.

Process.Start(...) returns the process that you started. I expect that if you check the StartInfo property on that, it will be populated.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting a different Process instance back from GetProcessesByName that falls into the latter case of the statement on MSDN.

Answer (score 3):

Process.StartInfo appears to be empty always!!!

I got entire running process list and try to dump values in StartInfo, but all 100+ processes' StartInfo fields are empty.

From MSDN:

"If you did not use the Start method to start a process, the StartInfo property does not reflect the parameters used to start the process. For example, if you use GetProcesses to get an array of processes running on the computer, the StartInfo property of each Process does not contain the original file name or arguments used to start the process."

You'll have use WMI to get that info for now.

Answer (score 1):

Ugh, that is frustrating.  I think they could probably make that documentation a little clearer as it's easy to read that as "if you do use Process.Start then that information will be available".

Guess I'll have to use WMI after all, ah well.