# sed command gives incorrect output when run as a System.Diagnostics.Process

Tags: c#, .net, sed, process

Given a text file helloworld.txt containing the following line:

> hello/world

The following `sed` command will output the file contents with the line removed:

```
sed '\:^hello/world:d' helloworld.txt
```

However if the command is run as a System.Diagnostics.Process:

```
var process = new Process
{
    StartInfo =
    {
        FileName = "sed",
        Arguments = "'\\:^hello/world:d' helloworld.txt",
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false
    }
};
process.Start();
while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
{
    Console.WriteLine(process.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
}
process.WaitForExit();
```

Then the output is "hello/world" (i.e. the matching line is not removed).

Why is this?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("'\\:^hello\\/world:d' helloworld.txt");` outputs `'\:^hello\/world:d' helloworld.txt` for me, this is different than `'\:^hello/world:d' helloworld.txt`.

Comment: @Quantic the question had a typo, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by adding an additional backslash:

```
"'\\\:^hello/world:d' helloworld.txt"
```

Based on information found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287812/backslash-and-quote-in-command-line-arguments).