# .Net Process Class command not processing quotes

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, command-line-interface

I have a command line process that I would like to call:

```
process.StartInfo.FileName = "docker"; 
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "--format='{{(index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports \"5000/tcp\") 0).HostPort}}' " + containerId;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "./";

process.Start();
process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(ErrorOutputReceived);
process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputReceived);
process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
process.BeginErrorReadLine();
process.WaitForExit(); //this limit might need to be changed
process.ErrorDataReceived -= new DataReceivedEventHandler(ErrorOutputReceived);   
process.OutputDataReceived -= new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputReceived);
```

Now, if I use the command at the command line, it works.  If I call this code, it fails.  I have tracked it down to the quotes around "5000/tcp".  Dotnet has some fun rules that prevent it from processing this correctly, even though I am escaping them properly.  I have tried these rules and they are giving me some problems.  Anyone able to tell me what the escaping characters should be?

Here is the link I saw, but it is not working out as they mention:  [Backslash and quote in command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287812/backslash-and-quote-in-command-line-arguments)

Answer (score 1):

```
process.StartInfo.Arguments = 
    @"--format='{{(index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports \""5000/tcp\"") 0).HostPort}}' " + containerId;
```

Notice `@` and double quotes `""`.

Comment: Ha, figures that this is the only combination I haven't tried.  This worked for me! Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind, I misspoke.  This doesnt help either.  I think its because its a mix of single and double quotes.  If you just have one set quotes, its fine.

Comment: That's strange. How about creating `docker.bat` that contains your .exe call with args and then run that batch via Process? You can pass containerId to batch file call, too.

Comment: Yeah I could probably use a batch file instead, but I thought that it wouldnt scale as well as just calling a command directly.

Comment: Always write the batch in user temp before running ;)

Answer (score 0):

I could not get this one to work, but I changed the query:

```
"--format=\"{{range $p, $conf := .NetworkSettings.Ports}} {{$p}} -> {{(index $conf 0).HostPort}} {{end}}\""
```

With this, I will get a list of ports instead.  Ill have to process it more, but it gets rid of the single quotes.  As long as I have one set of quotes I will be fine.