# Accessing a file which is opened by another exe (opening properties of this file) from that exe's code

Tags: c#, .net

I've written a custom exe. Files of a sepcific type can be openend with this exe (properties -> open with). Now, in this exe's source code I'd like to access the file which ran the exe (e.g. the path to the file). Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can a Win32 process get the pid of its parent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185254/how-can-a-win32-process-get-the-pid-of-its-parent)

Comment: what do you want to do with it?

Comment: Actually, I've no idea what the question is now, having seen how others have interpreted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you want the path from where the explorer opened the file; in normal cases this will be passed to your program as an argument (like "C:\\myapplication.exe filename")

Modify your Main-method (program entry) from

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
```

to

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
```

If the args collection contains something, that is the passed filename

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   if (args.Length != 0) 
   {
        string fileName = args[0]; // something like this
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use "Open with" in Explorer for a file or simply double-click on a file if it's permanently assigned to a program, the path of the file is passed to the program via command line arguments. So you have to examine the command line arguments in your program to determine if it was called with any arguments that could be a file to open.
See here for example: [How to access command line parameters outside of Main in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742630/how-to-access-command-line-parameters-outside-of-main-in-c-sharp)