# pass telephone to default windows softphone while its running

Tags: c#, winforms, ipc

I developed a softphone for windows, I know how to register it as default tell application by reading this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/384994/how-to-associate-a-softphone-with-a-phone-url), but I don`t know how **get**  arguments sent from a web application or another win application while my softphone is running.

The standard code to call tell app from web app is something like this:

```
window.open("tel: 05525825");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you setup the protocol URL keys correctly your application will be run with the data in the command line (E.g. `args[]` in `main()`)

To pass data to an *already running* instance of your application the easiest way is to use the [`StartupNextInstance`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.StartupNextInstance);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) event provided by `VisualBasic.ApplicationServices` and re-process new incomming command lines:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices;

namespace Foo
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var applicationBase = new ThisWindowsApplicationBase();
            applicationBase.StartupNextInstance += (sender, e) => { applicationBase.HandleCommandLine(e.CommandLine); };
            applicationBase.Run(args);
        }
    }

    class ThisWindowsApplicationBase : WindowsFormsApplicationBase
    {
        internal ThisWindowsApplicationBase()
            : base()
        {
            this.IsSingleInstance = true;
            this.MainForm = new Form1();

            this.HandleCommandLine(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Skip(1));
        }

        internal void HandleCommandLine(IEnumerable<string> commandLine)
        {
            this.MainForm.Text = "Processing: " + commandLine.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Note this will not fire for the first run.

Comment: Thanks Alex, Is there any tutorial for the solution you suggested ?

Comment: Thanks. So I need to write my handler for StartupNextInstance event

Answer (score 1):

If you have registered your application for the scheme `tel:` and the Command is "yourapp.exe %1", then you can read them from the commandline arguments as explained in [How to access command line parameters outside of Main in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742630/how-to-access-command-line-parameters-outside-of-main-in-c-sharp):

```
string arguments = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
string phoneNumber = arguments[1];
```

Of course you need to do some sanity checking before bluntly accessing and using the array element.

Comment: Thanks @codecas, I would check it out. But is there a listener or event handler for this to read Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();?