# how to pass argument to a process

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, process, arguments, program-entry-point

Is there a way to pass a string argument to a process which is spawned from my own process.

I have in my main application:

```
Process.Start(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "wow.exe");
```

`wow.exe` is another app I created. I need to pass argument to this exe (a string). How can I achieve this typically?

What I tried:

```
 ProcessStartInfo i = new //........
 i.Argument = "cool string";
 i. FileName = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "wow.exe");
 Process.Start(i);
```

And in the main of `wow` application i wrote:

```
static void Main()
{
    //print Process.GetCurrentProcess().StartInfo.Argument;
}
```

But I never get my string there in second application's Main. [Here is a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344056/why-is-startinfo-processstartinfo-always-empty) which asks `why`, but no `how to solve it`..

**Edit:** `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[1]`, it has to be. Nevertheless, got it working. Accepted @Bali's answer as he cameup first with this answer. Thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the arguments passed you can either use the `string[] args` in your `Main`, or you can use `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs`.

Example:

```
Console.WriteLine(args[0]);
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example how you can get arguments passed to your exe:

```
static void Main()
{
   string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

   string firstArgument = args[0];
   string secondArgument = args[1];
}
```

or change your main method a bit:

```
static void Main(string []args)
{}
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want a

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
}
```

where `args` contains the arguments you passed in

Comment: I tried this, but still I get empty string for `Process.GetCurrentProcess().StartInfo.Argument;` in the main

Comment: You don't need that. Try `Console.WriteLine(args[0].ToString())`

Answer (score 1):

In your `wow.exe` program.cs

```
static void Main()
{
     //Three Lines of code 
}
```

change it to

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     //Three Lines of code 
}
```

`string[] args.` will now contain your arguments passed to your exe.

Or you can use

```
string[] arguments = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
```

Your arguments are broken by space `" "`.

Comment: I can not see anything similar in Main().